# How to make ubuntu one sync existing files and folders inside a shared folder

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I have shared my `Documents` folder with Ubuntu One. It has the big green tick and any new files or folders I create in there get synced. But I want all the existing files in there to sync as well.

How do I enable that?

Comment: Does the Ubuntu One application tell you that it has stopped syncing? Because sometimes it is still syncing even when the green tick appears. Take into account that the proccess can be really slow.

Comment: It would tell me file sync was up-to-date.  I had to reboot after some update, after that it worked properly.  Go figure, windowseske flakesome.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: How was i supposed to know that it was a bug before i asked the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is a bug in Ubuntu 11.10 that causes new Cloud Folders (folders set to sync) to not sync their contents until you restart Ubuntu One.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/869920
The fix for this bug should appear very soon in your regular updates. In the meantime you can restart the Ubuntu One processes by opening a Terminal and running the following commands one at a time.

This command will quit the Ubuntu One syncdaemon.

```
u1sdtool -q
```

This command will start the Ubuntu One syncdaemon.

```
u1sdtool -c
```